# C function call parameters get scrambled

Tags: c++, function

I am using Netbeans with gcc for this,   and I find that the value of the function arguments are being corrupted between the calling function and the called function.

In myfuns.h:

```
float dotprod( float u1, float u2, float u3,  float v1, float v2, float v3 );
```

In myfuns.c

```
 float dotprod( float u1, float u2, float u3, float v1, float v2, float v3 )
 {
    float res= u1*v1+u2*v2+u3*v3 ;
    return res;
 }
```

In main.c

```
 ...
 float dp=dotprod( rx, ry, rz,  ddx, ddy, ddz );
 ...
```

If I print the values of u1,u2 etc in the dotprod() function,  or examine them with the
debugger,   the values are different to the values of  rx,ry  etc in main.c

If I convert the arguments from  float  to  float*,   the problem seems to go away.  I also
tried adding a dummy integer argument before and after the 6 float arguments,  the first one is OK but the last one also get corrupted.   I have spent hours trying to spot the error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you use `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: What are types of `rx, ry, rz,  ddx, ddy, ddz`?

Comment: Any warnings on `-Wall` level?

Comment: I suggest that you post compilable example code that shows the problem. Also let us know the tools that you're using.

Comment: Are you including myfuns.h from main.c?

Comment: Yes, myfuns.h is included in main.c The arguments rx,ry,rz, ddx,ddy,ddz are all simple float variables and they each have a value assigned to them before dotprod() is called. I did not try using double. When I changed the function arguments to float* and the actual arguments to &rx, &ry etc and the variables inside the function to *ux, *uy etc, then it works. I have several other simple functions in myfuns.h and myfuns.c which appear to work OK. Your example is interesting, because that is the sort of bogus numbers I am seeing. I will go double-check that.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.2.    I mostly use Java on this and have not used C all that much,  I usually use Visual Studio for C.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are the types for all those variable in `main()` specified as `float`?
2. Is the prototype for `dotprod()` visible when you call it? In other words, does your main file have `#include "myfuns.h"`?

In particular, answering no for that second question means that the compiler will make certain assumptions about the arguments being passed that makes the value a different width, or interpret them in a different way.

For example, consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float x = 1.5, y = 2.5;
    fn (x, y);                       // <-- compiler makes assumptions.
    return 0;
}

void fn (float a, float b) {         // <-- compiler should complain
    printf ("%f %f\n", a, b);        //     about bad assumptions.
}
```

which outputs:

```
0.000000 1.937500
```

That's really *not* what you would expect. This was compiled with gcc and the slew of warnings that were spat out should have been reason enough to go back and check the code <sup>(a)</sup>.

In this particular case, my `int` and `float` types are the same width (32 bits) but, because the compiler thinks the function accepts `int`, it will convert those floats to that type first. Unfortunately, when the function looks at those `int` values on the stack, it interprets them as `float` types, which are encoded quite differently.

It can be even worse if your expected and actual types are different widths, since you may find you try to use more data than what was put on the stack.

This particular code sample can be fixed simply by inserting:

```
void fn (float, float);
```

before `main()` (or swapping `main()` and `fn()` around) so that the prototype is not assumed. This results in no warnings from gcc and the correct output:

```
1.500000 2.500000
```

Basically, you have to ensure that the caller and callee agree on the parameters passed. That includes such things as calling convention, data types and parameter counts, among other things. A mismatch in *any* of these will cause you problems.

---

<sup>(a):</sup> Such as the following, on my system:

```
testprog.c: In function ‘main’:
testprog.c:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fn’
testprog.c: At top level:
testprog.c:9: warning: conflicting types for ‘fn’
testprog.c:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘fn’ was here
```

Comment: I don't get any compiler warnings.    Is there some compiler setting I should use to get more warnings ?

Comment: If you're using `gcc`, it's a good idea to use `-Wall -Wextra`, since `gcc` seems to have a rather deficient definition of "all" :-)

Comment: Added -Wextra  (  I don't know why they hide the place that this has to be added so obscurely ),   got a few messages about unused  parameters  but nothing about this problem.   Anyway it appears to have gone away when the .cpp file is removed from the project,  I am guessing there is an incompatility between the c and c++ files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing *the same* type of data with the function parameter, i.e. the size and represent.

For a very simple test, try this in main:

```
float dp=dotprod( (float)rx, (float)ry, (float)rz,  (float)ddx, (float)ddy, (float)ddz );
```

Comment: I also tried  dotprod(int, float, float, float, float, float, float, int );

Comment: and the first int parameters works OK and the one at the end doesn't work OK.

Comment: Can you share more context from main.c, and how you compile the program?

Comment: I can't even tell whether it is actually using gcc or g++  because the project configuration has both of them.

Comment: I suspect that though they are both float but they are not identical in size or representation.

Comment: I've just found out that another function for the project is in a .cpp file and is being compiled with g++    and all the other functions are in c files and compilied with gcc.     And this other .cpp function isn't even called in the program yet.     And when I delete this function from the project  and remove the file to somewhere else,   the problem goes away.

Comment: Well I suspected that too about the floats,   but really,   whose floats are not 32 bits ?     And the main.c and the myfuns.c are being compiled in the same project by the same compiler.   I have encountered problems with floats before doing transmissions between different brands of computer, back in the old days,  nothing like this in a simple program which this is.

Comment: I also considered whether there could be some anomaly in the way in which the function call parameters were being put on the stack.   But when I did the test with the dummy int parameters,   the first int paramater was OK and the last one was no good.

Comment: As you have the debugger, I suggest you can watch the stack to tell what is being pushed by the caller and how is the stack used by the function.

Comment: Seems to be OK now.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The cause was not conclusively determined.   Removing a cpp function from the directory with c functions in it,  made the problem go away.  I don't know if that was the genuine cause, or not